# xmpp authentication failure

Tags: ios, objective-c, xmpp

I am using Openfire 3.9.3 on Linux OS, i am trying to authenticate user
But always get this message

> failure xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-sasl" not-authorized/

i already searched and used number of questions and answers but none worked for me!
here is my code , please help me!

```
+(void)CreateConnection{

if (xmppStream == nil){
    xmppStream = [XMPPStream new];
}
    if (![xmppStream isConnected]) {
        xmppStream.hostName = @"104.238.96.31";
        xmppStream.hostPort = 5222;

        [xmppStream setMyJID:[XMPPJID jidWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@@%@",JID,serverIP]]];
        [xmppStream addDelegate:self delegateQueue:dispatch_get_main_queue()];
        NSError *error2 = nil;
        [xmppStream connectWithTimeout:10.0f error:&error2];

        if (error2 != nil){
            NSLog(@"here is the connect error %@", [error2 localizedDescription]);
        }

    }}
```

the delegate:

```
+(void)xmppStreamDidConnect:(XMPPStream *)sender {
    [self UserAuthenticationCheck];
}
```

the function:

```
+(void)UserAuthenticationCheck{
NSError *error = nil;
[xmppStream authenticateWithPassword:JPASS error:&error];
}
```

this used to work before but now i don't know what happened!Any suggestion is appreciated!!

Comment: Could you check by replacing 104.238.96.31 to DNS server name ex. xmpp.com, to support iPV6

Comment: thanks @AvijitNagare, its fixed now , i just updated my open fire to latest! fixed all the required plugin!! :D